angular upgradation from 15 to 16 package errors
im upgradining my agular application from 13 to 18
in the process of upgrading each version i got below package errors in application
1.SatDatepickerModule
SatDatepickerModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
datepicker-module.d.ts(9, 7): This likely means that the library (saturn-datepicker) which declares SatDatepickerModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
(alias) class SatDatepickerModule
import SatDatepickerModule
@license
Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license

SatNativeDateModule
'SatNativeDateModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
index.d.ts(15, 40): This likely means that the library (saturn-datepicker) which declares SatNativeDateModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
(alias) class SatNativeDateModule
import SatNativeDateModule

any solution how this can be resolved?.

Unfortunately, the datepicker does not support ivy and will not work for higher versions of angular ( approx angualar 14+ ).
You should switch to a datepicker that is maintained regularly and supports the latest versions of angular ( Angular material datepicker, etc).
You should abandon this datepicker and switch to a newer version, else the authors should update the datepicker to support angular latest versions, but I think the package is archived, so its better you switch to a newer date picker library.
